# Unable to Install git package on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, git

So, I'm trying to install git on Ubuntu 14.04...
When I typed:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

It said:

```
E: Unable to locate package git
```

So after some time searching I ran:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E1DD270288B4E6030699E45FA1715D88E1DF1F24
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu trusty main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/git.list"

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install git
```

and now I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
       Recommends: patch but it is not installable
       Recommends: rsync but it is not installable
       Recommends: ssh-client but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me someone? Thanks for your replys...

Comment: have you tried to install only `git`? not `git-all`

Comment: @GTRONICK Hi, yes I have tried all suggested -> `git`,`git-all`,`git-core` in this topic is a code for only `git` edited